# Album app process in Django

Tags: python, django

I want to know how to display images separated by albums onto a page in Django. So far, I've learned how to do so with the line

`<img src="{% static "images/python-logo@2x.png" %}">`

in my html file.

structure:

```
/PersonalWebsite
   /static
      /img
         /albums
            /album1
               img1
            /album2
               img2
            ...etc
```

What I want to do is have a few album thumbnails out and upon click, all the images from the album should be displayed. I believe I would do this with an AJAX request. I am probably going to categorized these photos with tags and put names one them and other characteristics. This would be done in my `models.py` which I have: (though not completed)

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import admin
import os
from PersonalWebsite.settings import MEDIA_ROOT

class Album(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 60)

    def __unicode__(self):
         return self.title

    def get_image_by_album(self):
         images = []
         for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT, 'albums', self.title)):
             mypath = os.sep.join(os.path.join(root, file).split(os.sep[4:]))
             images.append(mypath)
             return images

class Tag(models.Model):
    tag = models.CharField(max_length = 50)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.tag

class Image(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 60, blank = True, null = True)
    #image = models.FileField(upload_to = get_upload_file_name)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank = True)
    albums = models.ForeignKey(Album)
    width = models.IntegerField(blank = True, null = True)
    height = models.IntegerField(blank = True, null = True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.image.name 

class AlbumAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ["title"]
    list_display = ["title"]

class TagAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["tag"]

class ImageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ["title"]
    list_display = ["__unicode__", "title", "created"]
    list_filter = ["tags", "albums"]

admin.site.register(Album, AlbumAdmin)
admin.site.register(Tag, TagAdmin)
admin.site.register(Image, ImageAdmin)
```

My "get_image_by_album" parses through the albums and appends the path to "images" list. Thats as far as I've got right now =/ I also want to set up an admin so I can maintain the site easily later on. I think I am going to make a view method that will simply get the list of image paths and display it that way. I am open to suggestions! let me know what you think! I also want to set up an admin interface that would enable me to upload and edit meta data from the photos manually but I will figure out how to do so later.

Comment: This question is a bit vague. Exactly what do you need help with?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I am trying to create a simple gallery app in my django project but as I am new, I dont know how to start or format this. Ive made a bit of progress however I am still a bit stuck. Currently I have my models set up and a method to parse through all my images but that is about it.

Answer (score 1):

I built a very simple gallery app using django-photologue.  http://gallery.gentryart.us

Comment: I want to do thsi without using an app so I can learn more about Django =/ thank you for your suggestion!